# How to install updates on multiple windows servers automatically?

Tags: windows, update

Let's say that I've got a lot of different Windows servers to install updates on.
I.e. about 50 servers; running Windows server 2003, 2008, 2012 (service packs, R2 editions, and such), some 32bit and then some 64bit versions.

Every once in a while, I'd like to run Windows update on these. The WSUS server gathers the updates, and the servers can use that source to install updates from.
**But I don't want to go through the update process manually!**

I.e. *switching the video/keyboard input to a specific server, pressing Ctrl+Alt+Del, filling in the admin credentials, logging in, waiting for the Windows update bubble to show up, clicking on the update button* ... all this, fifty times in a row, that's rather futile.

**Is there a lazy man's solution that would execute the update process for me?** As far as I'm concerned, a dead-simple interface with a single "Update the servers" button of sorts would be tremendously helpful. If the interface provided a centralized overview (which servers are in the middle of installing the updates, which ones finished successfully, which ones failed updating some updates, which ones are in a need of restart, and such), that would be terrific.

If there's some setting up to do to achieve this, let's hear it!

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way is setting a deadline on the needed updates on your WSUS server.
The servers then install the updates on their own.

Setting a deadline will cause clients to install the update at a specific time http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc708585%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: _Setting a deadline will cause clients to install the update at a specific time_ http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc708585%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You mean like using group policy [to configure automatic updates and the default WSUS server?](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/328010)

### 1. Add the WSUS Administrative Template

In Group Policy Object Editor, click either of the Administrative Templates nodes.
On the Action menu, click Add/Remove Templates.
Click Add.
In the Policy Templates dialog box, select `Wuau.adm`, and then click Open.
In the Add/Remove Templates dialog box, click Close.

### 2. To configure the behavior of Automatic Updates

In Group Policy Object Editor, expand Computer Configuration, expand Administrative Templates, expand Windows Components, and then click Windows Update.
In the details pane, click Configure Automatic Updates.
Click Enabled and select one of the following options:

**Notify for download and notify for install.** This option notifies a logged-on administrative user prior to the download and prior to the installation of the updates.

**Auto download and notify for install.** This option automatically begins downloading updates and then notifies a logged-on administrative user prior to installing the updates.

**Auto download and schedule the install.** If Automatic Updates is configured to perform a scheduled installation, you must also set the day and time for the recurring scheduled installation.

**Allow local admin to choose setting.** With this option, the local administrators are allowed to use Automatic Updates in Control Panel to select a configuration option of their choice. For example, they can choose their own scheduled installation time. Local administrators are not allowed to disable Automatic Updates.

Comment: You're right, and I've even said that to people before, so I'll edit.

Comment: @CanadianLuke done, was that *your* d/v??

Comment: No, it wasn't mine. But looks better :)